# How do I make this foreign key naming convention?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to use a Fluent NHibernate naming convention to make my foreign keys follow this naming standard:

```
fk<table name>_<foreign table name>_<underscore delimited column list>
```

...but using the conventions, I can't seem to get the table names.  I can do something like this:

```
var fkIndexConvention = ConventionBuilder.Reference.Always(x =>
    x.ForeignKey(string.Format("ix{0}_{1}", x.Class.Name, x.Property.Name)));
```

which seems kinda close, but I'd really like to reference the two related tables and the involved column(s).  How can I do this?

Comment: ... that's a heck of a stretch to call that a duplicate.

Comment: Why? As you, the OP wants to have the foreign table's name in its key. Furthermore, it shows the only way this would be possible at all: Deriving from `ForeignKeyConvention`.

Comment: The answers may be related to some degree, but reading that question certainly did not give me a useable answer to my own; classifying  this as a duplicate question when different things are asked for and answered simply because they may be abstractly related comfortably fits my definition of a "stretch".

Comment: That's why four others also need to mark your question as a duplicate before my action has any more effect than just being a comment. Actually, I marked it as a duplicate, because I wanted to help you but didn't have the time to actually answer your question with a well-researched answer. Marking it as a duplicate seemed to be the easiest way to give you at least *some* information. Take it or leave it.